# Sorting Username

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to sort Username correctly?

For example I do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM  `members` WHERE username LIKE  'bx%' ORDER BY username ASC
```

**Result**:

```
bx1
bx10
bx11
bx12
bx13
bx14
bx15
bx16
bx17
bx18
bx19
bx2
bx20
bx21
bx3
bx4
bx5
```

I want to return like this:

```
bx1
bx2
bx3
bx4
bx5
...
bx15
bx16
```

and so on

Comment: Wow I got up votes ... I wonder why?

Comment: It's a generic question applicable to a wide audience, asked in a clear and concise way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `members`
WHERE username LIKE 'bx%'
ORDER BY LENGTH(username), username
```

The fact that you need to do this tells me your schema is denormalized. If possible, store the integer part of the username in a separate column if you need to do operations on it.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8738/3/0)

Comment: Ooooh, I like this answer!  +1  But what happens if there's also a username `bxa1`?  It will be ordered between `bx1` and `bx123`... perhaps not what the OP wants?

Comment: @eggyal That's right, you need a custom function at that point to do a natural sort.

Comment: @RedFilter It looks better with uppercase haha

Comment: @NikolaK. Looks like yelling to me...edits like that are an arms-race war and don't contribute much to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I already have a member_id (PK) field anyway.. I just need to order `bx*` usernames for the report page.. Thanks :)

Comment: @user791022 If `member_id` is the number in the `username`, then you want this query instead: `SELECT * FROM members WHERE username LIKE 'bx%' ORDER BY member_id`

Comment: @RedFilter No I dont think that will work. For example: bx3 is member_id = 4 and bx2 is member_id = 10

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a user defined function which takes the string and returns an expanded string. The assumptions are: the string contains only one numeric component which is at the end and is less than the the maximum integer size determined by the padding in the fn 
Eg ABC1234 -> ABC00001234
ABC34 -> ABC00000034
Impliment the following steps

- Starting at the last character, Iterate through the passed string
  character by character (decreasing position) until the first non
  numeric character is found. (C)
- get the length of the numeric part  (4)
- add a mutiple number of "0" characters to the numeric part of
  the string (this determins the max size of numeric part handled) 
  giving (eg) 00001234
- Prefix by the non numeric part of the string
  giving ABC00001234
- Output

Sort by output
You can also add a calculated field (which uses the function just created) which will give this value returned and create an index on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM  `members` 
WHERE username LIKE  'bx%' 
ORDER BY cast(substring(username, 3) as unsigned) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If the phras bx is fixed,

```
SELECT * FROM  `members` WHERE username LIKE  'bx%' 
ORDER BY replace(username,'BX','')*1 ASC
```